# mod-rewrite in the eZ Publish Framework

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the eZ Framework as part of my new job.

mod-rewrites are handled in 2 sections of the GUI admin interface:
1 - URL translator
2 - URL wildcard

The URL translator essentially handles single rewrites
The URL wildcard is... as the name suggests meant to be wildcard, so can handle *

At the moment, when a new competition is created a new "URL translator" needs to be added. This gets ugly when there are 25 competitions and 15 are old and out of date.

This is what the data entry person has to enter at the moment for a new competition:
URL = /places/competitions/the-name-of-the-comp/process
TO = competition/process

We have tried writing a wildcard catch all, so new comps don't have to be entered as a single rewrite:
URL = /places/*/process
To = competition/process

But, as you may have guessed, it is not working.

If anyone is an eZ Publishing master and knows if this can be done i would be very appreciative.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Hi John, do you get any specific error message when creating the wildcard URL forward ? And which version of eZ Publish is used ? Cheers.

Comment: No, however it turns out I was writing the wildcards correctly but was fully of-fey with the modules in use. Our system is currently straddling an old and new site.. the actions are changing thus my wildcard was catching the wrong action... Thanks though.. :)